# Eclipse SDK are suddenly missing?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

Well am running on Ubuntu using eclipse 3.7 Indigo
i used to have Google plugin for GAE and GWT, both were working great until today i found out this strange scenario

-Plugins are shown as installed (Help-->About eclipse platform---)
-A Red error appears while building projects using these Plugins saying " GWT SDK is not installed" ALTHOUGH they are installed
-Tried creating a google web application and it showed that the sdk files are missing from .eclipse directory!!!!!!!!

How should i solve this problem without the need to re-install eclipse and its plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quit eclipse, then:

```
sudo cp ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_*/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info /usr/lib/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
```

Answer (score 0):

Close Eclipse and open it again. It happens to me from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to import all plugins again to eclipse although they are present in eclipse directory !!
Weird and solved